# Enviar dados de uma activity para outra

Tags: android, android-activity, intent

Boa tarde, tenho tentado passar um EditText de uma activity para outra, porém não estou conseguindo.

Activity A.

```
listaViewLivros.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
 {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                view.setSelected(true);
                Intent intent = new Intent(AddActivity.this, FinalActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("ChaveTitulo", edtTitulo.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
```

Activity B.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_final);
        saidaTitulo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.saidaTitulo);
        String novoTitulo = getIntent().getStringExtra("ChaveTitulo");
        saidaTitulo.setText(novoTitulo);
       
    }
```

Não consigo em momento nenhum passar a informação para dentro do "saidaTitulo".

Answer (score 0):

Tenho aqui um pequeno exemplo de um projeto meu:

Atividade A

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SensorActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("name", name);
                                MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
```

Atividade B

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
        String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");

        tvWelcomeMsg = findViewById(R.id.tvWelcomeMsg);
        
        String message = "Welcome " + name;
        tvWelcomeMsg.setText(message);
```